# Como pegar erros em requisições AJAX?

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar erros no envio da requisição e trata-los na aplicação, de forma resumida a função trabalha dessa forma.

https://jsfiddle.net/n1p4k9jb/

Não coloquei a mesma que está na minha aplicação para poder simplificar a resolução do problema, a diferença é que na minha aplicação ela possuí callbacks para as requisições.

Funciona perfeitamente quando a requisição é completada, daí eu pego os dados e a aplicação continua, porém quando ocorre qualquer falha, nenhum dos alerts que coloquei para indicar que ao menos caiu no bloco de execução é chamado.

Outro erro que não consigo pegar, é caso o usuário perca a conexão com a internet, é possível testar no próprio navegador, no caso o Chrome tem uma opção para simular que está desconectado, no console é gerando um erro descrito como `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`, mas não caí em qualquer bloco de execução que eu possa tratar o problema.

Como posso pegar erros de requisições no AJAX?

Não desejo utilizar JQuery ou qualquer outra biblioteca.

Comment: Cara aqui funcionou perfeitamente, coloquei uma url inválida e apareceu o alert mostrando a mensagem failed.

Comment: Eu não consegui pegar o erro quando dá problema de cross-domain ou desconectado. Você poderia testar a condição de "desconectar" da Internet? Pode ser utilizando as ferramentas do desenvolvedor no próprio navegador, o Chrome tem uma opção pra simular que você não está com internet, esse é o principal erro que não consigo pegar.

Comment: Hm... beleza, vou tentar aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá Renan já entendi seu erro, É o seguinte, quando você realiza uma requisição e está sem internet, sua requisição é interpretada como uma requisição para outro domínio assim acarretando nesse problema do CORS, para resolver isso basta adicionar o header que habilita o CORS de qualquer domínio, segue o código:

```
function send (method, url, data)
{      
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.ontimeout = function()
    {
        alert('timeout');
    }

    xhr.onload = function() 
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) 
        { 
            if (xhr.status === 200) 
            {
                alert('success');
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert('failed');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('failed');
        }
    };

    try
    {
        xhr.timeout = 10000;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') //Linha modificada.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        alert('failed');
    }
}

send('POST', '/echo/jsonp/', null);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão Leonardo, porém infelizmente eu não posso utilizar esse meio por questões de segurança. Eu precisava que o catch pegasse o erro gerado pelo xhr.send(), assim eu poderia trata-lo na aplicação.

Comment: hm..., vou dar uma olhada nisso.